# sql - @curRow based on column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm creating rank system so I need to set rank position for every user.
I do this:

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS position,
                Sum(point_user.amount) AS points
FROM        users u
JOIN        point_user ON u.id = point_user.user_id
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
GROUP BY
u.id
ORDER BY
position ASC
```

And I'm getting:

```
+----------+----------+
| position | points   |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | 86       |
|        2 | 239      |
|        3 | 45       |
+----------+----------+
```

Now, how can I set row number, based on points?
Should looks like:

```
+----------+----------+
| position | points   |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | 239      |
|        2 | 86       |
|        3 | 45       |
+----------+----------+
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT (@curRow := @curRow + 1) as position, 
                points, 
                u2.id
FROM (SELECT Sum(pu.amount) AS points
      FROM users u JOIN
           point_user pu
           ON u.id = pu.user_id
      GROUP BY u.id
      ORDER BY points DESC
) upu, users u2
CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT @curRow := 0
) params
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query, it might be sufficient to change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY points DESC` -- because that seems to be your intention.

However, MySQL has a known problem with variables and `GROUP BY`.  The solution is simply to use a subquery:

```
SELECT (@curRow := @curRow + 1) as position, points
FROM (SELECT Sum(pu.amount) AS points
      FROM users u JOIN
           point_user pu
           ON u.id = pu.user_id
      GROUP BY u.id
      ORDER BY points DESC
     ) upu CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRow := 0) params
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! But I have one more question - how can extend this about additional columns? eg. userID, etc. I do this (update in question) but I getting about 1 600 000 records (should be 1129)

Comment: The inner `ORDER BY` is probably ignored by the Optimizer.  What version are you running?  What does `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` say?

Comment: @Vertisan . . . You can extend this to additional columns -- in fact, you can just include additional columns in the subquery.  If you mean anything more than that, you should ask another question, with sample data and desired results.